# Absolute maxima and absolute minima

Tags: calculus

Consider the following graph :

[image]

Then which of the following is true-

(i) No extrema in $ \ [a,b] \ $

(ii) Absolute maxima and absolute minima $ \ [a,b] \ $

(iii) Absolute maxima and No minima $ \ [a,b] \ $

(iv) Absolute minima and No maxima $ \ [a,b] \ $

**Answer:**

From the above graph I see that the function has no minima $ \ [a,b] \ $ because the function is discontinuous at its lowest value.

But as far as I  can understand is that the function has absolute maxima at $ x=a \ $

**So option $ \ (iii) \ $ is correct** .

**Am i right ?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is correct.

The point that is not attainable and represented as a hollow circle is called the infimum.